# Confused about the time complexity of nested loops and looking for tips

Tags: big-o

Lets say I have two codes:

Code A:

```
for i = 0;
for j = 0;
while(i<n){       // O(n)
    while(j<n){   // O(n)
       printf("hello");
       .....
```

**Running time  = o(n) x O(n) = O(n^2)..**

Code B:

```
int result = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < n/2){    //O(n)
result += arr[i];
i += 1;
    while(i >= n/2 && i < n){   //O(n)
        results += arr[i];
        i +=1;
        }
```

**Running time = O(n)**

**How come for Code B we DO NOT MULTIPLY the two O(n) to get O(n^2) like we did for Code A?? Very confused about how to determine running times.**

Comment: Suppose you had something like A, but the two loops were *not* nested, they ran one after the other. Do you see why that would be O(n)?

Comment: yes, but these are all nested.

Comment: The second code should be nested is it not?

Comment: In B the loops are nested, but they act as if they aren't; the inner loop won't run until the last iteration of the outer loop. That's why B is O(n).

Comment: I see, now that I inspect it again, the second while loop only runs after a while. SO, the first while loop will run without the second one for a short period. HOWEVER, for any future problems, is it safe to assume that if not for this special case of code B, we always multiply when there is a nest?

Comment: In general, if your outer loop is doing `O(n)` amount of work, and for each turn the work done of the inner loop is `O(k)` then you just multiply the work done together `O(nk)`. However, in this case the work done of the inner for loop is not the same for each turn, so you cannot merely multiply the work done to get the total

Comment: It is not as simple as "always multiply when there is a nest, except for this one special case". In general you must understand what the code *does*, not just its outline.

Comment: I see.. and kinda off topic, but if the loops are on the same level (not nested)we can just merely take the longest running time out of two?

Comment: @user3718584 Yes you are right, if the complexity of loop A and B are `O(n)` and `O(m)` respectively, the total work done is given by `O(n) + O(m) = O(n + m) = O(max{n, m})`

Comment: Alright, thank you both for answering! I will mark a check for chiwangc since that is only way to close topic, but I also give it because you were really helpful like Beta. I wish I could give accept multiple answers >.>... Thanks again guys~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give a run of code B in our head:

Suppose that `n` is quite large, say at least 100. Initially we have `i = 0`, so the condition for the outer loop is `true`, `i` will then increase by `1` due to line 5 (`i += 1`). So at this point we have `i = 1`, however in this case the condition the inner loop is `false`, so we just continue to the next turn of the outer loop.

The conditions for the outer loop and the inner loop remain to be `true` and `false` respectively until `i` becomes `n/2 - 1`, at this stage, the condition for the outer loop is `true`, and so `i` increases to `n /2`, and in this case the condition for the inner loop becomes `true` as well. So `i` will be increased up to `n` by the inner loop.

At last, we have `i = n`, the conditions for the loops are both `false`, and it will not loop further.

So the complexity is given below:

```
i          Work done
------------------------
0          1
1          1
2          1
.          .
.          .
.          .
n/2-2      1
n/2-1      n/2 + 1
```

So the total work done is:

```
(1 + n/2 - 2) * 1 + 1 * (n/2 + 1) = O(n)
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. I see my fault was in the fact that I did not analyze the code, but only tried to solve jsut by definition. However, for any other case, excluding this special code, we can just multiply correct?

Comment: Please refer to my comment to your question regarding when you can *multiply the work done of the inner loop and the outer loop*

Comment: I ahve commented to your reply, please read if you have time.